# python save numpy array with only non-zero elements

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have an array with most of the elements are zero.

```
A =  [ 1,0,2
       2,3,0
       0,0,4 ]
```

I want to save this as

```
rowid[0] colid[0] 1
rowid[0] colid[2] 2
rowid[1] colid[0] 2
rowid[1] colid[1] 3
rowid[2] colid[2] 4
```

here rowid and colid are arrays which maps the array indices to the actual entries in an original file.

How can I do this without using a for loop ?.

Comment: There is a scipy.sparse package that handles matrices like this.

Comment: @hpaulj, i am looking for a way to write such an array in a plaintext file in the specified format

Comment: Should be easy iterating through `argwhere`.with your own line formatting.

Comment: Do you want your output to literally have the string `"rowid[0]"` etc. ?

Comment: Come to think of it, `savetxt` could be used a fancier format such as `fmt='row[%d] col[%d] %d'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A = np.array(A).reshape(3, 3) # make A a 3x3 numpy array 
i, j = np.where(A != 0) # find indices where it is nonzero 
v = A[i, j] # extract nonzero values of the array 
np.savetxt('file.csv', np.vstack((i, j, v)).T, delimiter = ',') # stack and save 

# @Daniel F suggestion is to make header with array shape and add delimiter kwarg
np.savetxt('file.csv', np.vstack((i, j, v)).T, delimiter = ',', header = str(A.shape))
```

Comment: Probably want a `header` value  in `savetxt` to store the original shape of the array, so it can be rebuilt correctly if it is very sparse.

Comment: and to set `delimiter = ','`if you want a proper `*.csv`

Comment: Fixed a bit of formatting and added `delimiter = ','` to your original answer